# Compare two Tables SQLSE

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to know if that possible to compare two columns in two different tables in one database using C# with SQLSE.  if the two table has the same data in order, i can say the two tables are match; otherwise, there is no match.

// More info

I want to compare two column has repeated value the two column vlaues come from actual combination of visits for two patients and i want to check do they visit the hospital on the same date and rational insted to go for every 5 combination and compare the match i want to compare the whole table

Comment: Need some clarification. Are you saying you want to compare the columns of each table? so `table1` has columns `a`, `b`, `c`, and `table2` has `a`, `b`, `d` - so they would not match? or are you saying you want to compare the data in say column `a` of each table? Also, order likely doesn't mean much unless you have something to order by.

Comment: Have you read about INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS? You can run a SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on any Database constraining the outputed data in many different ways

Comment: I have two different tables with the same columns but i need to see the match of this two table on specific two columns and i need to get there is match or not without getting the match data

Comment: Table1 has three column  A  B  C  and table 2 has the same column A B C   I need to know the all data in column c in table 2 are match the data in table 1 in the same column

Comment: what type of data is `C`? char integer?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood (otherwise please add more information):

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC FROM Table1 WHERE ColumnC IN (SELECT ColumnC FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to compare the *data* in the primary key columns of two tables; you could do something like the following and if CNT is greater than 1 then they do not match:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) CNT
FROM 
        X
        FULL OUTER JOIN Y
            ON
            X.primaryKeyColumn = Y.primaryKeyColumn 
WHERE 
        X.otherColumn IS NULL 
        OR 
        Y.otherColumn IS NULL
```

Your question is a little vague. You seem to be concerned about `ORDER`. Do you consider the following two columns matching or not?:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer  actually I want to compare two column has repeated value  the two column vlaues come from actual combination of visits  for two patients and i want to check do they visit the hospital on the same date and rational insted to go for every 5 combination  and compare the match  i want to compare the whole table

Comment: I got a message that FULL OUTER JOIN is not supported on SQLSE

Comment: ok - try syntax similar to that suggested by UNeverNo - it should work ok